# Do i need to create a separate webpage for response URL as well as Request URL to integrate with iPay88?

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am developing an android mobile app and I do not understand why I need to provide a Request, Response and Backend URL to integrate with iPay88. As far as I understand, iPay88 has an SDK where I can just compile. Can i just create another activity in android studio or do I need a webpage (e.g. ASP .NET)?

Comment: Just create an activity in your mobile app in which you have to pass payment request object to iPay88[compiled from SDK].